# Python: Plot graphs of .csv-file and switch with mousebutton

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a .csv file of data of form

| Date | Company 1 | Company 2 | ... | Company n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 100 | 20 | ... | 123 |
| 02.01.2021 | 50 | 1 | ... | 455 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8.11.2021 | 20 | 23 | ... | 122 |

The company names I've saved in a pickle file.

My aim is now to switch the plots between the different companies, e.g. by clicking with left mousebutton.

I tried the following code based on the article [here](https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/4620496/how-to-interactively-switch-between-plots-or-selectively-hide-and-show-data-on-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import itertools#

with open("file1.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    tickers = pickle.load(f)
df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df.set_index('Date')
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ylim(ymax=500, ymin=0)

cyc = itertools.cycle()
i = 0

for ticker in tickers:
    if(i < 2):
        cyc.append(df[ticker])
    i = i + 1

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2))

line, = ax.plot(next(cyc))

def onclick(event):
    line.set_ydata(next(cyc))
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

But first I get following error:
TypeError: cycle expected 1 argument, got 0

And second I don't know, if I'm on the right way in general. Maybe their is a natural much more easy way to solve my problem.

Comment: Why not use [bokeh or plotly](https://towardsdatascience.com/get-interactive-plots-directly-with-pandas-13a311ebf426)?

Comment: Thanks don't know both of them. I will try it soon.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: as you can read in error message - it needs `.cycle(list)` but you have only `.cycle()` BTW: even article in your link has `.cycle((y1,y2))`. You can't create empty `cycle` - and you can't `append()` to `cycle`. I think you need `cycle(df[ tickers[:2] ])` or `cycle([  df[tickers[0]], df[tickers[1]] ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in error message - it needs `.cycle(list)` but you have only `.cycle()`.

Even article in your link has `.cycle( (y1,y2) )`.

You can't create empty `cycle` and later `append()` to `cycle`.

You have to first create list with data and next use it with `cycle()`

```
data = [ df[tickers[0]], df[tickers[1]] ]
cyc = itertools.cycle(data)
```

---

**BTW:**

I don't know what you have in `tickers` but I think if you want to do it with `for`-loop then you don't need `i`

```
data = []
for ticker in tickers[:2]:
    data.append(df[ticker])
```

or using `list comprehension`

```
data = [ df[ticker] for ticker in tickers[:2] ]
```